# Creating a safe environment for users to work with a database

Tags: macos, firewall

I have a Mac computer with a sensitive database. I want multiple users to be able to log on to my computer and work with that database, but prevent them from running any applications that could possibly send data from that database to outside computers.

Could anybody please provide me with some pointers what software I should be looking at?

Many thanks
Jan

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: Thanks Cole. In fact, as I would like to repeat the same process for different projects, it would ideally not be a database-specific solution. That said, I would expect the data to be either in Excel or importable to a standard SQL database. Thanks!

Comment: It can be very challenging to prevent data leaks. Are you interested in making it difficult to copy data or impossible?

Comment: Thanks Cole. I think "difficult" should be sufficient, I'm not aiming for "impossible" here.